# How to get userinfo out of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to make a login and logout page out of WordPress. I think I need to use `currentuserinfo()` to logout, but it's too hard for me. When I test it, I could see.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
require_once("../soft/wp-config.php");
require_once("../soft/wp-load.php");
global $user_ID, $user_identity; get_currentuserinfo(); if (!$user_ID) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
    echo("wp login");
  else{
    echo("wp logout");  
  }
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    echo("wp logout");
  } else {
    echo("wp login");
  }

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n"; ?>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: your exact question is not clear , please explain that?

Comment: you can add the wordpress hook add_action('wp_logout', 'your_function'); and trigger your_function on logout click function

Comment: @DeepKakkar sorry to my english skill.. i want get userinfo for logout